# Popup / Page XAML on another page XAML - UWP App

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a very simple UWP App, and I'm working on a new update that will bring some design changes. And in this new update I would like to have an "About" button, and when the user clicks the button opens a "popup" that shows more information about the app etc.

That is, what I want is that when you click this button it opens a smaller XAML page above of my XAML home page.

It is possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You would like to create new view and switch to this new view.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
    int newViewId = 0;
    await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondaryPage), null);   
        Window.Current.Content = frame;
        // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
        Window.Current.Activate();

        newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
    });
    bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
}
```

or you can just open a [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup) control.

Difference between these two approaches are that Popup control will always overlay application window. New view can be moved out of the app window bounds.

Related links:

[Show multiple views for an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/show-multiple-views)

[Popup code example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Popup-Control-in-universel-700d46d4)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go,

The code which goes in your `About Button Click`

```
        contentDialogAboutUs = new ContentDialog();

        Frame framabout = new Frame();

        framabout.Navigate(typeof(AboutUs));

        contentDialogAboutUs.Content = framabout;           

        await contentDialogAboutUs.ShowAsync();
```

You give information regarding your app in the **AboutUs** page

You will need to declare the `contentDialogAboutUs` as static so that it could be used in your **AboutUs** page to be closed.

```
public static ContentDialog contentDialogAboutUs;
```

and in the AboutUs page, close your "popup" using,

```
        HomePage.contentDialogAboutUs.Hide();
```

*HomePage* is my source page from where the AboutUs click was called.

Hope this helped you.